# lstlisting ignores float setting

Tags: floats, listings

My document starts with:

```
\begin{document}
\lstset{ %
  language=Java,
  float=tb
}
```

However all listings appear exactly just where they have been defined, e.g. this one:

```
\begin{lstlisting}[label=fig:jaxrs-annotated-resource-example,
                   caption={Example of a JAX-RS annotated Resource class (by Marek Potociar)}]
@Path("atm/{cardId}")   
public class AtmResource {  
`  
  @GET  
  @Path("balance")  
  @Produces("text/plain")   
  public String balance(@PathParam("cardId") String card,   
                        @QueryParam("pin") String pin) {    
    return Double.toString(getBalance(card, pin));  
  }
\end{lstlisting}
```

Do you already see sth. wrong or do I need to find a minimal document with this issue? My full document is here: https://github.com/thkoch2001/bachelor-thesis/blob/master/latex/restful_groupware.tex

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although this seems clearly to be a bug, a work-around is the define a new listing environment:

```
\lstnewenvironment{javalisting}[1][]
  {\lstset{language=Java,float=tb,#1}}% \begin{javalisting}[...]
  {} % \end{javalisting}
```

Comment: Danke! Der Workaround funktioniert. Ich hatte nur Probleme, weil ich das \lstnewenvironment ohne die "Kommentare"(?) nach den % Zeichen kopiert habe. Oh latex...